# iOS and RESTful web service encryption

Tags: ios, encryption, gps, sha

So here is situation:
I have GPS based app with a lot of sensitive data sending to server - GPS coordinates, users address book phone numbers and so on.
So I need to have it really secure.

I decided to encrypt data sent to server with HMAC+SHA256, decrypt there, encrypt response, send response to client, and decrypt there.

Question is - does my app need CCATS review and approval since I'm not using HHTPS with SSL and just sending data encoded with SHA256?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel - use https - really

Comment: Use https with SSL or not? And if yes, should I use self-generated certificate or buy in for example on GoDaddy.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use https - really.

You will have to have a 'real' certificate on your website as (last time I checked) the https built in to iOS will only work with 'real' certificates.  Note that this will probably cost you ~$100/year.

Comment: I know that they exist, but wasn't sure of their 'legitimacy'.  IOW, will a browser confirm that they come from a legitimate CA?

Comment: Yes, certificates from StartSSL are valid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. In theory any app that uses encryption needs CCATS review. If you ask directly to Apple, they will answer that (yes, I did ask them).